# why custom style for rating bar error inflating?

Tags: android, android-layout

i have a problem with a custom style for a ratingBar ?

```
03-26 15:22:12.229: E/AndroidRuntime(2075): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-26 15:22:12.229: E/AndroidRuntime(2075): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #54: Error inflating class android.widget.RatingBar
03-26 15:22:12.229: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
03-26 15:22:12.229: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
03-26 15:22:12.229: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
......
03-26 15:22:12.229: E/AndroidRuntime(2075): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse 'res/drawable/ratingbar_yellow.xml' as integer
```

my ratingbar_yellow.xml

```
<item
    android:id="@+android:id/background"
    android:drawable="@drawable/rate_star_small_off"/>
<item
    android:id="@+android:id/secondaryProgress"
    android:drawable="@drawable/rate_star_small_half"/>
<item
    android:id="@+android:id/progress"
    android:drawable="@drawable/rate_star_small_on"/>
```

my style

```
 <style name="yellowRatingBarSmall" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/ratingbar_yellow</item>
    <item name="android:secondaryProgress">@drawable/ratingbar_yellow</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">14dip</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">14dip</item>
    <item name="android:isIndicator">true</item>
    <item name="android:indeterminateOnly">false</item>
</style>
```

in my layout

```
<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/restaurant_rating"
    style="@style/yellowRatingBarSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     />
```

Answer (score 1):

> Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse
>   'res/drawable/ratingbar_yellow.xml' as integer

I think problem is your declaration of `ID`. You're doing it incorrect.

```
android:id="@+android:id/background"
```

it should be like this:

```
android:id="@+id/background"
```

Comment: what I wanted to do was change the color of the stars, it manages to make adding pictures of another color (Yellow) and changing the property,  android:progressDrawable="@drawable/ratingbar_yellow"      but thank you very much.